# Passing parameters to javascript loaded in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Basically I have injected an iframe like so on a page:

```
<iframe src="http://myserver.com/content.js?title="blah"&date="March" id="frame">
```

On this page, I will change the src url, to pass in different parameters.

It will take the parameters and render a widget.

Should I be using a static html instead to display the parameter contents in the iframe?

```
<iframe src="http://myserver.com/content.html#title="blah"&date="March" id="frame">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to not put double quote marks inside your double quoted value.